# php cgi htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cgi

i try to execute cgi but failed.
i include following lines in  .htaccess

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +ExecCGI
```

abc.com/ is equivalent to the /home directory

abc.com/compare is equivalent to the /home/compare directory

abc.com/compare/contact is equivalent to the /home/compare/contact directory

.htaccess file located in contact directory

but server returns the following message.

> Internal Server Error The server
>   encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to
>   complete your request.Please contact
>   the server administrator,
>   admin@abc.com and inform them of the
>   time the error occurred, and anything
>   you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.More information
>   about this error may be available in
>   the server error log.

what is the problem

one more thing is can i see phpinfo() that cgi is enable or not??

Comment: ... How do you expect `phpinfo()` to help you if you can't run a CGI script in the first place?

Comment: Should be moved to ServerFault.

Comment: Do what the message in your browser says: look in the error log of your web server.

Answer (score 1):

Is CGI enabled on your server?
You have to enable it in the httpd.conf, take a look at: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html